# Cannot install unittest package in pycharm

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm

I tried to install 'unittest' package in Pycharm. But an error occurred when installing it. The repository of the Pycharm is https://pypi.python.org/simple. 
The python version is 2.7.13.

[image]

How do I resolve this problem??

Comment: try to remove the check on "specific version" option

Comment: I tried it. But it didn't work.

Comment: Please click "Details" and attach screenshot with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you want **THAT** `unittest` module? That's a 0.0 version of some package with what looks like little to no support/development. `unittest` has been a default package in python since [Python 2.1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).Since you are using Python 2.7, you should be able to just do

`import unittest`

and you should automatically have access to the `unittest` framework.